# How to repeat radio buttons using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, radio-button

Im wanting to repeat radio buttons using php. Below is the html form

```
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1">1                  
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1">1                  
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1">1
```

Basically, i have 4 groups of questions with rating 1-6 (how would i do it so i dont need to write out all this html code over and over, is there a shorthand method using php so that the selected one also goes into a mysql database too?

Completely confused and new to php, any help would be great.

Comment: show code of your current attempts

Comment: With loop for, while, ...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thats the problem, ive no idea how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, the FOR loop is your best bet here however, you can expand a little by adding simplicity and expanding the commands.

```
$rating = 6; //This sets the highest rating number

for($i=0 $i<$rating; $i++){

  //This echos the input by rating, if rating is 6, it'll repeat 6 times.
  echo "<input type=radio name=RadioGroup1 value='" . $i . "'>\r\n"; 

}
```

Now for the other half of the problem.

When posting information to a database, you need to send it to another page for processing and storage (or the same page if you handle it correctly).

This is a basic way to store THIS radio group (this is in procedural style):

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

$query = "INSERT INTO myTable (RadioGroup1) VALUES ($_POST['RadioGroup1'])";
mysqli_query($link, $query); //replace link with your database connections variable
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at loop [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

```
//$i => groups (/4)
//$a => radio buttons (/6)
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
  for($a = 1; $a <= 6; $a++){
    echo '<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup'.$i.'" value="'.$a.'">'.$a.'<br/>';
  }
  echo '<br/><br/>';
}
```

And the function

```
function loopMe($group, $answer){
  for($i = 1; $i <= $group; $i++){
    for($a = 1; $a <= $answer; $a++){
      echo '<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup'.$i.'" value="'.$a.'">'.$a.'<br/>';
    }
    echo '<br/><br/>';
  }
}
```

For use it

```
loopMe(3, 4);
```

Comment: Why you changing the radio group name? I'm assuming he wants the group identifier the same, no? If only one radio button can be selected from the group, the name's must be identical..?

Comment: He is creating 4 `RadioGroup` groups, each containing 5 radio buttons. Hence the nested loops.

Comment: Right. I see now. Dazed out on the second `FOR`

Comment: Is there a way i can break each 1-6 buttons so there not in 1 row?

Comment: @FBHY, That's great, do you have any idea how i could turn this into a function so i can use the same over again, for example.. set of 4 questions, with 6 answer options. But 3 SETS of those 4 questions

Comment: @Box, this is a better solution over my answer. Go this route. It's cleaner. :)

Comment: @box I did a little function. check it out

Comment: @FHBY last question, is there anyway i could style the radio buttons so i can give them a margin on top?

Comment: @box of course, you set a class and a style attribute (  `echo '<input type="radio" class="myclass;" name="RadioGroup'.$i.'" value="'.$a.'">'.$a.'<br/>';` )

Answer (score 1):

Try a `FOR` loop function...as below:

```
<?php 
for ($x=0; $x<=6; $x++)
   {
   echo '<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="'.$x.'">'.$x;
   }
?>
```

To learn more about this function, visit:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: this comes up with an error -- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'radio' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\feedback.php on line 67

Comment: Saw my mistake...try again. :)

Answer (score 0):

see this example below... hope this helps you...

page1.php

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form id="frmQuestion" method="post" action="page2.php">

        <p>Question 1</p>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" checked="checked" />1
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" />2
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3" />3
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="4" />4
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="5" />5
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="6" />6
        <br/>

        <p>Question 2</p>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1" checked="checked" />1
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" />2
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3" />3
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="4" />4
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="5" />5
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="6" />6
        <br/>

        <?php
            for($i=3; $i<=20; $i++)
            {
                echo "<p>Question " . $i . "</p>";

                for ($j=1; $j<=6; $j++)
                {
                    if($j == 1)
                    {
                        echo "<input type='radio' name='question". $i ."' value='". $j."' checked='checked' />" . $j;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<input type='radio' name='question". $i ."' value='". $j."' />". $j;
                    }
                }

                echo "<br/>";
            }
        ?>        

        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    </body>
</htm>
```

page2.php

```
<?php

echo "question 1:" . $_POST["question1"] . "<br/>";
echo "question 2:" . $_POST["question2"] . "<br/>";
echo "question 3:" . $_POST["question3"] . "<br/>";
echo "question 4:" . $_POST["question4"] . "<br/>";

// for more.
for ($n = 5; $n<=20; $n++)
{
    $question = "question" . $n;
    echo "question". $n . ":" . $_POST[$question] . "<br/>";
}

?>
```